# Creating threads from the same class but with different methods connected in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, python-multithreading

Classes should be generic, right? I've got an example of multithreading using **threading** module, but it overrides the run method, so in fact this class can only create a thread connected to the **print_time** method. How can I make a thread of the same class, but connected to a different method, for example **print_time_2**?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import threading
import time

exitFlag = 0

class myThread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, name, counter):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.name = name
        self.counter = counter
    def run(self):
        print "Starting " + self.name
        print_time(self.name, self.counter, 5)
        print "Exiting " + self.name

def print_time(threadName, delay, counter):
    while counter:
        if exitFlag:
            thread.exit()
        time.sleep(delay)
        print "%s: %s" % (threadName, time.ctime(time.time()))
        counter -= 1

def print_time_2(threadName):
    while True:
        print "Its me, %s" % (threadName)

# Create new threads
thread1 = myThread(1, "Thread-1", 1)
thread2 = myThread(2, "Thread-2", 2) #how to connect this thread to print_time_2

# Start new Threads
thread1.start()
thread2.start()

print "Exiting Main Thread"
```

Comment: Classes should not be generic but concrete. Seriously, unless you define precisely what *you* mean with "generic", I can only assume the typical use of this word, and then it has its advantages *and* disadvantages.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating your own thread class, you can import `Thread` class from `threading` module and then invoke it for functions (and specify arguments as necessary)

Example -

```
from threading import Thread

def print_time(threadName, delay, counter):
    while counter:
        if exitFlag:
            thread.exit()
        time.sleep(delay)
        print "%s: %s" % (threadName, time.ctime(time.time()))
        counter -= 1

def print_time_2(threadName):
    while True:
        print "Its me, %s" % (threadName)

t1 = Thread(target=print_time, args=(1, "Thread-1", 1) )
t2 = Thread(target=print_time_2, args=("Thread-2" , ) )

t1.start()
t2.start()
```

document for python threading class - https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html

And yes, if args only consists of one argument, you need the last ',' as given in the example.

Comment: Supporting deriving from the `Thread` class was a bad choice by Python in the first place, you don't derive from `File` in order to access a file either. Using this approach is a good advise!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with classes (good idea):

Build two new classes, inheriting from myThread, having both their implementation of print_time function.

Comment: But it generates a lot of code. Isn't it better to use one class to create multiple threads?

Comment: It does not generate more code than you wrote, only two new lines to put your to print functions in classes inheriting `myThread`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have found this kind of solution to my problem. Could u comment on it, if it's good or bad? It works ok for me though...

```
import threading
import time

class FuncThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, target, *args):
        self._target = target
        self._args = args
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        self._target(*self._args)

# Example usage
def someOtherFunc(data, key):
    while True:
        print "Thread 1: data=%s; key=%s" % (str(data), str(key))
        time.sleep(1)

def someOtherFunc2():
    while True:
        print "Thread 2"
        time.sleep(0.2)

t1 = FuncThread(someOtherFunc, [1,2], 6)
t2 = FuncThread(someOtherFunc2)
t1.start()
t2.start()
```

Comment: Still prefer my version but it clearly depend the context, divergence of implementations...